# PHP/mysql result set not repeating the same user

Tags: php, mysql

In php I have a results set that show similar results of another. How do I have the similar result set include one result for per user instead of showing multiple results per user.

For example, I want the similar result set like this unique to each user:

```
user A 
user C
user F
user B
```

---

not like this:

```
user A
user C
user A
user A
user D
user C
```

etc... because it here it shows different results for the same user i.e. user a, c.

In php do I need to create a foreach loop so the result set doesn't repeat the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT` in your SQL query.

A bit like this :

```
select distinct username
from users
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php in PHP or *SELECT DISTINCT* in MySQL...